# How to quickCheck on custom ADT in PureScript?

Tags: purescript, quickcheck, property-based-testing

For using QuickCheck, I'm trying to implement the Arbitrary instance:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary (class Arbitrary, class Coarbitrary)

data Arith = Lit Int | Add Arith Arith | Neg Arith

derive instance arithEq :: Eq Arith

instance arbitraryFoo :: Arbitrary Arith where
    arbitrary = arbLit <|> arbAdd <|> arbNeg where
        arbAdd = do
            a <- arbitrary
            b <- arbitrary
            pure $ Add a b
        arbNeg = do
            a <- arbitrary
            pure $ Neg a
        arbLit = do
            x <- arbitrary
            pure $ Lit x
```

But PureScript told me that

```
The value of arbitraryFoo is undefined here, so this reference is not allowed.
```

And when I change my code acroding to the guide from the error message:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary (class Arbitrary, class Coarbitrary)
import Control.Lazy

instance arbitraryFoo :: Arbitrary Arith where
    arbitrary = fix $ \arb -> let
        arbAdd = do
            a <- arb
            b <- arb
            pure $ Add a b
        arbNeg = do
            a <- arb
            pure $ Neg a
        arbLit = do
            x <- arbitrary
            pure $ Lit x
        in arbLit <|> arbAdd <|> arbNeg
```

I still got some error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

So, how can I fix that? and why `Arbitrary` can not be derived automatically?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent it from generating an infinitely recursive structure, you should make the generator `sized`, and then `resize` by `-1` each time it is used recursively.

Here's an example of a JSON generator using that technique: https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-argonaut-core/blob/37fc57c722851b1936c438db750aa8195dc630c7/src/Data/Argonaut/Gen.purs. Although the `Gen` is abstracted with `MonadGen`, the same principle applies if you want to implement an `Arbitrary`.